# WPF PrintVisual Memory Leak

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I am having a bit of an issue when using `PrintDialog.PrintVisual`, as it seems to be causing a memory leak.

In this application I create a WPF control which is only used for printing, it is never shown on the screen. Here is an example of the code:

Calling the print

```
public void PrintDocument()
{
   PrintUserControl printControl = new PrintUserControl();
   printControl.Print();
}
```

The Print User Control

```
public class PrintUserControl
{
    public PrintUserControl()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        const double width = 5.8 * 96;
        const double height = 8.3 * 96;

        this.Measure(new Size(width, height));
        this.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(width, height)));
        this.UpdateLayout();

        var dlg = new PrintDialog();

        PageMediaSize pageMedia = new PageMediaSize(PageMediaSizeName.ISOA5);
        dlg.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize = pageMedia;
        dlg.PrintVisual(this, "FooDocument");
    }
}
```

I have profiled this application and when calling the `PrintUserControl.Print` method there appears to be memory leak, many instances of `LayoutEventList+ListItem` and `ConditionalWeakTable`. If I comment out the `PrintUserControl.Print` method, then there are no leaks, but obviuosly nothing prints.

Am I not disposing something I should be?

Comment: Check the objects you're using for Dispose methods. If they have them, call them. Also, remember objects do NOT disappear when they go out of scope, only when GC runs which can be some time after.

Comment: None of the objects are disposable unfortunately. I am using ANTS performance profiler, and have been tracking IDisposable objects, but non are left undisposed.

Comment: Does it tell you what's ready for GC? I think Sysinternals Process Explorer will do that if not.

Comment: The two 'Classes' that are Gen2 and growing are `LayoutEventList+ListItem` and `ConditionalWeakTable`

Comment: Changed this to an answer, as the comment got too long...

Comment: @NickWilliams Does setting the page size help? `PageMediaSize pageMedia = new PageMediaSize(PageMediaSizeName.ISOA5, 559.68, 793.92);`.  I'm not sure it will but creating a media size like that leaves the width and height = null.  Lastly, I'm guessing you're drawing a table or list of items, how many items on in the collection?  Maybe post some XAML to show us the controls that are getting drawn.  For instance, drawing a list inside a Viewbox might be drawing every element, which could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

So they've been properly cleared up, but GC hasn't run and won't until it decides it needs to. (This is usually when the machine gets short of memory.)

This is basically how .NET works, and in general how Garbage Collected languages work.

The advantage is you don't have to worry about whether to use Free or delete, or memory leaks where you forget to use either; the disadvantage is that your process uses more memory until the Collector gets around to cleaning stuff up.

It won't run until there is a need to clean stuff up as otherwise it is taking resources (CPU etc) from your app when they really aren't needed elsewhere. It will only do that when some conditions apply, such as low system memory available. I believe that the circumstances in which GC decides to run are 'an implementation detail' and should not be relied on as they will change between .NET versions.

A reasonable like is [this one from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can also search on 'non-deterministic finalisation', which had a number of people excercised when .NET was in iuts original beta.

Comment: After time, my machine with 2GB of RAM sits at 2GB usage, so its not that GC doesnt get invoked. Using ANTS profiler I can manually call a full GC, and the elements are still there.

Comment: OK. I must have misunderstood what ANTS was showing you - sorry. What is LayoutEventList? Searching for it doesn't come with anything much. Where are you using it? Where is it defined?